# networkx.exception.NetworkXError: Input graph is not chordal

Tags: networkx

This is my adjacency matrix for a graph `G_csp`:

```
array([[1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.]])
```

Why am I getting the following error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graph_csp_test.py", line 85, in <module>
    G_chordal = nx.complete_to_chordal_graph(G_csp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/networkx/utils/decorators.py", line 766, in func
    return argmap._lazy_compile(__wrapper)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<class 'networkx.utils.decorators.argmap'> compilation 4", line 4, in argmap_complete_to_chordal_graph_1
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/networkx/algorithms/chordal.py", line 402, in complete_to_chordal_graph
    if nx.is_chordal(H):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/networkx/utils/decorators.py", line 766, in func
    return argmap._lazy_compile(__wrapper)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<class 'networkx.utils.decorators.argmap'> compilation 9", line 5, in argmap_is_chordal_5
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/networkx/algorithms/chordal.py", line 83, in is_chordal
    return len(_find_chordality_breaker(G)) == 0
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/networkx/algorithms/chordal.py", line 331, in _find_chordality_breaker
    raise nx.NetworkXError("Input graph is not chordal.")
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: Input graph is not chordal.
```

The whole point of this `complete_to_chordal_graph` function is to take in a graph that is not chordal, and make it chordal. Why would it error that the input graph is not chordal?